# Simple variable test

Tags: c, bash

With Bash you can do a simple variable test like this

```
$ [ $foo ]; echo $?
1

$ foo=bar

$ [ $foo ]; echo $?
0
```

> The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null.

What would be a similar test with C?

## Edit

Lets say an `int` type for argument sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is implicit boolean conversion in C. So all of the following will print "bad":

```
int a = 0;
if (a) {                  // if a is nonzero.
    printf("good");
}
else {
    printf("bad");
}

char* str = NULL;
if (str) {                  // if str is nonzero. (NULL is zero).
    printf("good");
}
else {
    printf("bad");
}
```

Comment: Note that an empty, allocated string is considered true and that another check against `strlen()` (or `*str`) will be required.

Comment: Very good point. I definitely missed that case which is a natural expansion of this when comparing to shell scripts.